# I can't find maintenance tool in Qt5.5

Tags: qt

I have already installed qtbase and all, now I am trying to, install V-play in Qt, so I'm looking for maintenance tool, from the v-play website installation instruction detail :

> If you already have Qt 5 installed on your system you can add V-Play to that installation. Open the executable called Maintenance Tool and following these steps:

I am using Qt 5.5 , I can't find the maintenance tool .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have downloaded and installed Qt from the [Qt website](https://www.qt.io/) it will be located in the parent installation folder. For example, if you installed in `/opt` then the maintenance tool will be located inside the `/opt/Qt` folder.

I don't think the maintenance tool is present if you installed Qt using apt.

Answer (score 0):

At least as of Ubuntu 19.10, the Qt Maintenance Tool is simply not contained in the Ubuntu repositories. You have basically two options:

1. Download the [Qt Online Installer](https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer) from the Qt website and use that to install the desired versions of Qt. The Qt Maintenance Tool will then also be available at `/opt/Qt/MaintenanceTool`.

   You can delete the version of Qt Creator installed by this process if you prefer to keep the version from the Ubuntu repositories: `sudo rm -R /opt/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/`
2. Or you could use [`aqtinstall`](https://github.com/miurahr/aqtinstall/), an unofficial Qt installer that can be used to install any Qt on any target platform. It's equivalent in function to the Qt Maintenance Tool while being equivalent in terms of interface to `apt` (means, it's a commandline tool rather than a GUI tool, allowing scripting with it).